# Leer un .json desde python

Tags: python, json

tengo un .json con la siguiente estructura:

```
[
  {
    "Country": "Spain",
    "Age": "14"
  },
  {
    "Country": "China",
    "Age": "16"
  },
]
```

Intento leerlo con el siguiente método:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('json.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

pprint(data)
```

pero me lanza el siguiente error:

> ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

El JSON me lo devuelve el software Octoparse, por lo que no creo que esté mal formateado.

¿Cómo almacenar los valores en un json local a mi script?

Me gustaría que tuviese el siguiente formato:

```
{"14":"Spain","16":"China"}
```

Gracias.

Comment: @abulafia ha sido un error al pegar

Comment: Pues salvo por esa coma, el JSON es correcto y a mi Python me lo lee sin problemas. ¿Estás seguro que ese es el contenido del fichero que intentas leer? Ya que has seleccionado sólo parte para pegarlo en la pregunta ¿no tendría alguna cabecera o caracteres invisibles al principio que estén dando los problemas? Por otro lado ¿qué versión de python usas?

Comment: Python 2.7 y no parece haber caracteres ocultos...

Comment: https://anonfile.com/b6adv3f2b8/json.json

Comment: El fichero es el mismo, cambié los nombres de los campos aquí para simplificar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Diagnosis

Aunque el JSON que se pega en la pregunta es correcto (salvo por un error al copiarlo que ha dejado una coma al final que sobraba), cuando el usuario intenta las mismas operaciones sobre su propio JSON, obtiene el error `ValueError`, que no es muy informativo.

Tras algunas conversaciones con el usuario, obtengo el fichero json con que realmente está trabajando, e intento replicar la ejecución de su código con Python2 (que es la versión que el usuario usa), y efectivamente, aunque el JSON suministrado tiene aspecto correcto, obtengo el error:

```
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Si, en cambio, repito la ejecución usando Python3, el diagnóstico es mucho más preciso y confirma mis sospechas de que existen caracteres ocultos al inicio del fichero que están causando los problemas:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig): line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

### El problema

El fichero contiene al principio una serie de bytes denominados "BOM" (Byte Order Mark) que son invisibles al mostrarse por pantalla o cargarse en un editor, pero no al ser leidos desde un programa.

La misión de esos bytes, si el fichero fuera en UTF-16, es permitir a los programas que lo lean deducir la *endianity* de la arquitectura en la que el fichero fue generado (es decir, si es *little endian* o *big endian*). No obstante, en un fichero UTF-8 no tiene sentido introducir estos bytes porque el formato UTF-8 es inmune al problema de la *endianity*.

Sin embargo, muchos editores y programas Windows introducen estos bytes igualmente cuando salvan en UTF-8, y eso por lo que se ve no es compatible con el estándar JSON.

### Solución

Usando python3 es posible pasar a `open()` un parámetro que especifique el encoding del fichero a leer (si no se pasa, asume `utf-8`). En este caso habría que pasarle `utf-8-sig`, como el propio Python3 nos está diciendo en su mensaje de error.

Sin embargo, ya que el usuario utiliza Python2, no tiene la posibilidad de pasar ese parámetro al abrir el fichero, por lo que no nos queda más remedio que leer el fichero completo a una cadena de bytes, y después codificar esa cadena a Unicode, usando el formato en cuestión. Posteriormente usaremos `json.loads()` en lugar de `json.load()`, ya que así podremos pasarle la cadena unicode correctamente decodificada en lugar del fichero.

Es decir:

```
import json
with open("json.json") as f:
  raw_data = f.read()
data = json.loads(raw_data.decode("utf-8-sig"))
```

Esta solución ocupa más memoria que la de Python3, pues tenemos que cargar el fichero entero antes de parsear el json, mientras que en la de python3 se iría parseando a medida que se lee, pero ya que el fichero no es muy grande (61K) no hay problema.

Comment: Magnífico, muchas gracias!